# Issue with HTTP POST request iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest

So I have gathered this code to send a POST request to a web service however I keep getting this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

and I have looked to see what it means but do not understand responses in the context of this code.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

NSString *myRequestString = @"idvar=76";

NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"192.168.0.11/test/deleteerrand.php" ] ];
[ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: much appreciated! no error message, although now I have the issue that nothing seems to be happening lol! time to look through my PHP :P

just wondering, could you elaborate on why that works ?

Comment: you were passing invalid argument, [NSString stringWithUTF8String takes string not bytes. NSString class has already initWithData